# About this servlet + tomcat example, can not compile servlet using javac

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I am currently following the book Head First Servlets and JSP, and I got to the point on page 81 where the author asks to compile the servlet using javac.

I am having problems to execute that line of code. I think that my JAVA_HOME and etc must be set up correctly since I created a sample HelloWorld.java and 
 compiled it useing javac and it created the correspondent .class file.

I am failing to see the logic of this command, you specify a class path to the servlet-api.jar file and then you give it another path so it can execute the .java file? 
 I would like to get out of this hole I am in right now. These are the paths to my files:

C:\Users\Carlos L\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.28\bin\servlet-api.jar 
 and this is where my BeerSelect.java file is: 
 C:\Users\Carlos L\Tomcat\My Tomcat Projects\beer-v1\src\com\example\web\BeerSelect.java

so far i have been imputing: 
 javac -classpath C:\Users\Carlos L\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.28\bin\servlet-api.jar; classes:. d-classes src\com\example\web\BeerSelect.java

and I am getting this error:

javac: invalid flag: d-classes 
 usage:javac

This should not be this hard.

Answer (score 0):

First, yes **it is valid to compile against one jar and later run against a different one(s)**. In particular a jar named something**-api**.jar usually contains *only* the classes that constitute the Application Program Interface aka API, and is sufficient to compile programs that want to call something, but actually executing those calls requires additional internal classes that are packaged in jars using various names such as something-impl, something-body, plain something, or multiple jars such as something-basic something-core something-addon something-option etc.

Second, your book is apparently using the common (but not required or universal) scheme where the java source code files and compiled class files are in **separate, parallel subtrees** here named `src` and `classes`. Your particular sourcefile is apparently `src\com\example\web\BeerSelect.java`. The **syntax to run the java compiler** for this case is:

```
javac -classpath (classpath) -d classes src\com\example\web\BeerSelect.java
# or abbreviate -classpath as -cp, or use envvar CLASSPATH instead
```

That's hyphen then d, then a space, then the directory name here `classes`, then another space and the sourcepath (or multiple sourcepaths).

You shouldn't need to specify `classes` in the classpath initially, only the `servlet-api.jar` file. If you later compile *some* but not all sourcefiles of the `src` subtree, and previously-compiled classfiles for *other* sourcefiles are already in the `classes` subtree, you do need both the `servlet-api.jar` and the `classes` directory. On Windows you separate classpath entries by semicolon `;` and on Unix you use colon `:` but you should never mix them. So your case would include:

```
javac -classpath \path\to\servlet-api.jar;classes (rest as above)
```

except that your path name apparently includes a space `C:\users\Carlos L\...` so you must put the value in quotes:

```
javac -classpath "C:\users\Carlos L\tomcat-8.0.28\bin\servlet-api.jar;classes" (rest as above)`
```

As an alternative to typing this numerous times, you can put the value in envvar CLASSPATH

```
set CLASSPATH="C:\users\Carlos L\tomcat-8.0.28\bin\servlet-api.jar;classes"
```

and then simply do

```
javac -d classes src\com\example\web\BeerSelect.java
```

and similarly for any other classes in the the project as you come to them.